# Restoring values in form after display rotation

Tags: java, android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have the code below and the problem is that all inflated views have the same ids (as set in the `player_item.xml`) - so when I rotate the screen, all of them are restored with the same value. The easiest solution would be removing those ids and let android to genereate them automatically but I can't do this because I need them for positioning in the relative layout. Any ideas how can I solve this?

**player_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/player_name"
        style="@style/stats_edit_column"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/goals"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/goals"
        style="@style/stats_edit_column"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/assists"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/assists"
        style="@style/stats_edit_column"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**code**

```
for (PlayerStats playerStats : allPlayers) {
    View playerStatsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.player_item, null);

    TextView playerName = (TextView) playerStatsView.findViewById(R.id.player_name);
    playerName.setText(playerStats.getPlayerName());

    EditText goalsEditText = (EditText) playerStatsView.findViewById(R.id.goals);
    goalsEditText.setText(String.valueOf(playerStats.getGoals()));

    EditText assistsEditText = (EditText) playerStatsView.findViewById(R.id.assists);
    assistsEditText.setText(String.valueOf(playerStats.getAssists()));

    editLayout.addView(playerStatsView);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused "all views have the same IDs". If they had same ids in the XML (android:id) you would have a build error and looking at your XML that they all have different IDs. The ADT assigns each android:id name a unique int which is stores in R.java which is then compiled as a constant. You reference the view in code via R.id.someIdName which is an int constant, e.g. 28172128. They must be unique or your app won't build. I do see a problem though. When processing layout, the ADT goes top to bottom so layout_toLeftOf must come after the view it references. Or maybe explain a different way.

Comment: @Simon as you can see in the code, I inflate the layout above it and put the inflated view to `editLayout` which is a parent. All the children in the `playerStatsView` have android:id set in the XML... This code works but somehow all the inflated layouts behave as their children have the same IDs... Is it clear now? It's all visible in the code..

Comment: Yes, I was being a bit slow wasn't I?  If it was me, I'd think about putting the loop into onResume(), after editLayout.removeAllViews() or, use setId() to generate and remember the Ids, possibly by adding an increment which is 0-allPlayers.length-1 to the original ID so you have a direct link between the inflated child view group and the view.

Comment: @Simon but won't this cause layouts to fall apart? They will no longer have the right IDs for toLeftOf etc...

Comment: Being slow again!  I'm taking today off from SO ;) but see my answer below.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create a bean for every form and while moving to other activity set all form value to the bean and store the bean reference in to the shared preferences , so when u come back to the same activity simply reload all the values getting from the bean , this helps saving the state of your form

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping a reference to the playerStats in the tag?

```
for (PlayerStats playerStats : allPlayers) {
    View playerStatsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.player_item, null);

    TextView playerName = (TextView) playerStatsView.findViewById(R.id.player_name);
    playerName.setText(playerStats.getPlayerName());

    EditText goalsEditText = (EditText) playerStatsView.findViewById(R.id.goals);
    goalsEditText.setText(String.valueOf(playerStats.getGoals()));

    EditText assistsEditText = (EditText) playerStatsView.findViewById(R.id.assists);
    assistsEditText.setText(String.valueOf(playerStats.getAssists()));

    playerStatsView.setTag(playerStats);

    editLayout.addView(playerStatsView);

}

getViewForPlayerStatsByTag(PlayerStats playerStats){
    for (int i=0;i<editLayout.getChildCount();i++){
        view = (View)editLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if (view.getTag()==playerStats){return view;}
    }
    return null;
}
```

getViewForPlayerStatsByTag will return the player_item view group for those stats, null if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I think this won't help me. I would still have those `playerName`, `goalsEditText`, `assistsEditText` with the same IDs in each iteration... Just imagine the `playerStatsView` as an item in a `ListView`